# Water replacement for pressure-testing

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request, toxicity, conductivity, liquids

Due to circumstance, our Data Centre build has some delays and it currently looks like we're going to have to perform a hydrostatic test of our sprinkler system *with live computers in it*.

As I have an education as a chemist, *but haven't done any serious chemistry in >30 years* I thought of using another liquid than water to charge the sprinkler pipes and am looking for the following characteristics:

- Same order of magnitude of compressibility as good old H<sub>2</sub>O
- Non-corrosive to materials used in a Data Centre (Metal, plastic, ...)
- Non-flammable
- Non-conductive to electricity
- Non-HAZMAT
- Cheap (No liquid gold please, or the VP is going to blow a fuse) **;-)**

I tried googling a bit but could not find anything easily, so turning to the experts that deal with this on a daily basis as I've sent off the idea to the sprinkler installers already mentioning my preference for CHCl<sub>3</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>OH as a joke, but if they ask me which liquid I would propose, what would be the ideal solution to the above problem?

<sub>A citation to a PubChem or similar source would be appreciated</sub>

Comment: No, no, no... It *has to be water*. You can protect comps any way you wish, but using other liquid in water using one for test is just plain bad idea.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you elaborate _why?_

Comment: Chemists refer to water as "the unique solvent" for good reason. There is simply no other liquid with the range of properties you are looking for.

Comment: Water might be somewhat "unique", but it's just that the idea of **testing** if something works properly with *improper* liquid is bad. You might even break it.

Comment: What about testing in sections (say, per aisle), placing a bucket on a ladder -- just below such a sprinkler.  And if you have multiple of them, you probably find someones which are agile enough to hold such empty bucket for 5 min while standing on a ladder during such a test, too.

Comment: Water is the only liquid I know of that is not toxic or is considered hazardous waste when dumped in large quantities in a building (or anywhere else for that matter). As for a CPU, there is no liquid including water that I would dump on it.

Comment: We're procuring buckets, reverse umbrellas, tarpaulins, etc already but I was looking for something better and easier that we can do during the day instead of during the night shift.